# Variable syntax in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Should be a simple question, but I'm a Rails novice and just kinda hacking this together. What's the format to add in a variable to this syntax? Pseudocode:

```
 $var = '<html>' . $var2 . '</html>';
```

Except in ruby...

```
class PdfController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @html = %Q{
      <html>
      VARIABLE
      </html>
    }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Ruby interpolation:

```
class PdfController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @html = %Q{
      <html>
      #{ VARIABLE }
      </html>
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: It's worth nothing that any valid Ruby expression can go in the interpolation braces, not just variables.